# Pandas: Conditional Split on Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following question: I have the following table:

```
 A     B     C
 1     A     A
 2     A     A.B
 3     B     B.C
 4     A,B   A.A,A.B,B.C
```

Column A is an index (1 through 4). Column B lists the letters, which appear in column C before the point (if there is any, if there is none, this is implicit, so the entry in (C,1) = A is the letter after the (.) (so this entry = A.A).
And column C either lists both letters before and after or only after the point.

The idea is to split these points and lists up. So column C should first be split up by the comma to separate rows (that works). Problematic here is, whenever there are different letter possible in B - because after splitting up, B should also only contain 1 letter (the correct on for column C).

So the result should look like this:

```
 A     B     C
 1     A     A
 2     A     B
 3     B     C
 4     A     A
 4     B     B
 4     B     C
```

Can someone help me with ensuring, that column B contains the correct (i.e., fitting) information, which is denoted in column C?

Thanks and kind regards.

Comment: I don't understand how you get `4   B   B` and not `4   A   B`.

Answer (score 1):

First, stack your dataframe to get your combinations:

```
out = (
    df.set_index(['A', 'B']).C
    .str.split(',').apply(pd.Series)
    .stack().reset_index([0,1]).drop('B', 1)
)

   A    0
0  1    A
1  2  A.B
2  3  B.C
3  4  A.A
4  4  A.B
5  4  B.C
```

Then replace single entries with their counterpart and apply `pd.Series`:

```
(out.set_index('A')[0].str
    .replace(r'^([A-Z])$', r'\1.\1')
    .str.split('.').apply(pd.Series)
    .reset_index()
).rename(columns={0: 'B', 1: 'C'})
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  A  A
1  2  A  B
2  3  B  C
3  4  A  A
4  4  A  B
5  4  B  C
```

Answer (score 1):

With a comprehension

```
def m0(x):
    """Take a string, return a dictionary split on '.' or a self mapping"""
    if '.' in x:
        return dict([x.split('.')])
    else:
        return {x: x}

def m1(s):
    """split string on ',' then do the dictionary thing in m0"""
    return [*map(m0, s.split(','))]

pd.DataFrame([
    (a, b, m[b])
    for a, B, C in df.itertuples(index=False)
    for b in B.split(',')
    for m in m1(C) if b in m
], df.index.repeat(df.C.str.count(',') + 1), df.columns)

   A  B  C
0  1  A  A
1  2  A  B
2  3  B  C
3  4  A  A
3  4  A  B
3  4  B  C
```